# Is there a way to run server with a session-persisted database connection in Django?

Tags: django

As I develop the backend side, I also develop the frontend. As you have probably guessed, I have to do some REST requests on my server.

Well, there are a couple of solutions for that. I can use mocks on the frontend, or [a fake JSON server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). However, there are some cons to this approach:

- I have to remodel what I have on an already existing backend server.
- Dealing with authentication on a fake JSON server is not really comfortable.
- I have to write a lot of boilerplate if I want to go on mocking and unit testing approach.

Again, all the logic I want already exists in my Django project, so what I want is:

1. Run a dev server.
2. Set up a fresh new database.
3. **Provide some initial data.** Some fake users, posts, whatever.
4. Do my testing on my frontend project while the server runs.
5. Hit the kill signal. (CTRL+C)
6. Gracefully drop the database that I have created on step 2.
7. Shutdown the program.

I use `pytest` and `pytest-django`. They do exactly these when they set up a test environment, I was wondering if I can manually do that.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.9
- Django 2.2

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/ …?

Comment: That's one piece of the puzzle. What about cleaning it on shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used such integration-testing setup, but I’ve seen it somewhere.

You can run the [`django-admin testserver mydata.json` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#testserver) to spin up a testing server with data from a provided fixture. The way it was done in the example I saw was by making a custom Django command where instead of static fixture the testserver’s database was populated dynamically by factories. I don’t remember the details how it was implemented, though.

After the testserver was ready, the [Cypress tests](https://www.cypress.io/) were run. Backend and the frontend were wired by npm’s [`start-server-and-test` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test).

Application with similar setup can be checked out [here](https://github.com/ccnmtl/locustempus). Especially note the [custom testserver command](https://github.com/ccnmtl/locustempus/blob/master/locustempus/main/management/commands/integrationserver.py) as well as the [cypress commands](https://github.com/ccnmtl/locustempus/blob/master/package.json).

Comment: didn't know `testdata` subcommand existed until today.